# Plotting a histogram from cellvalues

Tags: matlab

I have a cellarray of dimension 100x1 of integer elements. How can I plot a histogram from this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cell2mat` to convert to regular matrix first, and them use `hist` command

```
hist(cell2mat({1,2,3,10,10,10}))
```