# How to plot a histogram from array

Tags: matlab

I have an array of size `a=<100x1 int32>`  such that `a(1)=2`, `a(2)=3` and so on. How can I plot a histogram from this data. 
when I directly try to plot using `hist(a)`, it shows the following error

```
Error using  .* 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.
```

Also in case the data is not integer suppose `a=<100x1 string>` such that `a(1)='Saturday'`, `a(2)='Monday'` and so on then how can I plot a histogram for this data.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055541/plotting-a-histogram-from-cellvalues ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert your data to double (or single, if you're concerned about memory) before calling `hist`:

```
hist(double(a));
```

If you want to produce a histogram of e.g. strings, you can use `grp2idx` to convert the data into numeric indices.

```
data = {'a' 'b' 'a' 'c'};
%# convert to numeric
[index,keys]=grp2idx(data)
index =
     1
     2
     1
     3
keys = 
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
%# plot histogram
hist(index)
```